# Swift cannot find private struct define in framework

Tags: swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I got a issue while using swift-bridge-header feature to access c code framework(liblinphone).
  A struct LinphoneCallParams which defined in types.h that can be found in framework header files.
  And the struct definition is as following

```
typedef struct _LinphoneCallParams LinphoneCallParams;
```

When I try to define a parameter

```
var callPara: LinphoneCallParams?
```

in swift file, Xcode will show this error notice "Use of undeclared type 'LinphoneCallParams'". 
    (No problem to access the other definition in this file, so the swift-briging-header file is without problem)
    Search the definition of _LinphoneCallParams, which is located in private.h that is not included in SDK.
    But the interesting thing is, if I use Object-C code to define this parameter

```
LinphoneCallParams *callParams = xxxxxxx();
```

Everything works correctly. I don't want to use Object-C code to implement this project. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The bridging compiler is quite aggressive in discarding things that it decides don't need to be there.

If `struct _LinphoneCallParams` doesnt actually exist then the related `typedef/typealias` wont make it into the generated header.

Compare these two examples.

`struct _BoodleParams` exists:

[image]

And makes this:

```
class Thing {
    var boodle = _BoodleParams(foo: 3, bar: 4)
    var doodle = _BoodleParams(foo: 2, bar: 1)
}
```

Or this:

```
class Thing {
    var boodle = BoodleParams(foo: 3, bar: 4)
    var doodle = BoodleParams(foo: 2, bar: 1)
}
```

equally valid code.

However when you remove the need for the `typedef` to exist in the counter part it is stripped during the bridging process.

[image]

Note that as long as the symbol `_BoodleParams` exists somewhere in the compiled Objective-C the typedef will carry across in the counterpart.

[image]

In summary, the reason `LinphoneCallParams` cant be instantiated in your Swift code is that either the symbol `struct _LinphoneCallParams` isn't visible to the bridging system or it doesn't exist yet.